# webdriver-manager update, Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am trying to install Protractor on the companies Windows laptop. One of the steps is to run `webdriver-manager update` command in the console. When running it, i am getting the following error. Do you know how can i bypass the error?

```
webdriver-manager update
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1084:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:606:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:436:38)
```

Comment: This needs more information. My guess is that you are behind a proxy.

Comment: Get the latest version of webdriver-manager. The fix is in for this. You will need additional flags to send proxy values.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue. I ran the following:

```
webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl=true
```

Then I re-ran my protractor script and everything worked.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time today. You're a true here

Answer (score 1):

I found out later that office WebSense was blocking the execution of the file. I went home and i was able to run it in my home internet.

Comment: This worked out quite well. Just had to disconnect office vpn and it stoppped complaining :)

Answer (score 1):

c:>webdriver-manager start --ignore_ssl

should work for you